# Xlib: unexpected async reply when testing Qt application from a separate QThread within same Qt application

Tags: qt, x11, qthread, gui-test-framework

I am trying to create a test for my Qt appication. The aim is to test the GUI of the application by moving the mouse around and clicking on QGraphicsItems or QWidgets using the X11 library.

The test is written as a plugin for my Qt application. It launches a separate QThread and in the run() function I do the mouse moving. Lets call this the 'test running thread'

However I also need to get the structure of the GUI i.e. the location of various widgets, so in the 'test running thread' I go through the QApplication::topLevelWidgets() and find the one I am interested in. Then I call mapToGlobal() on this widget to gets its global position. This position can then be fed to the X11 mouse functions to move the mouse over the widget.

This works generally but once in a while I get this error 'Xlib: unexpected async reply'
Some googling revealed that this can be due to setting QWidget positions or trying to update them from another thread.

But I simply get information about widgets in another thread. Why would that cause a problem ? :(

If all else fails, I am prepared to setup some kind of communication queue back to the main(GUI) thread. The 'test running thread' will place requests for information about widgets on the queue and the GUI thread can respond to them.

The reason why the plugin launches a separate thread to move the mouse is because the GUI must continue to respond to events otherwise the entire point of the exercise is lost. I know that I could also *not* use a thread, and simply *move the mouse in the main thread* calling processEvents() regularly. Thats the other option I have I guess.

Any ideas from someone who has been down this route before would be very helpful.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I simply get information about widgets in another thread. Why
>   would that cause a problem ? :(

Because you are still sending X protocol messages back and forth. toGlobal() is sure to query the X server about the actual position of the widget (since it may have been moved by some other mean). So unfortunately, 'just getting some information' is not a const operation as far as X is concerned. Actually, moving your mouse from the test thread is a big no-no as well for the same reason.

In your case, I would simply use a zero-timeout QTimer/processEvents and forget about the thread; it's not worth the trouble of setting up queues to move events back and forth, not to mention you need to add mutexes (!) to your code.

Comment: So I understand the processEvents() call to make sure that mouse events continue to get processed as it's moved from the same main(GUI) thread. But what is the reason you were also suggesting the use of a QTimer ?

Comment: I mean, even if the QTimer goes off and I am still moving the mouse across the screen, the code triggered from the QTimer wont run. Since we are doing everything in 1 thread now. Lets say I was calling processEvents() from the QTimer callback, it would not be called. So the response of the GUI as the mouse moves across the screen would be lost. That is why I was thinking that the GUI thread may need to be freed up and the mouse moved in a separate thread. Calling processEvents() from the mouse move function is a possibility though but that means mixing Qt and X11 code in the same function.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the use of processEvents(); this function should be called periodically if you are doing some heavy-duty calculations like encoding a movie or calculating a Mandelbrot fractal, i.e. you are tying up the CPU for a considerable time. By calling processEvents() **from your loop** you make sure the GUI stays responsive. Your case is different: you simply want to move the mouse around, emulate clicks and fetch some results. This can be done in a slot, called from a QTimer, which is handled by the main GUI thread and thus will update the GUI automatically.